# Android custom listview - can't show

Tags: android, listview

my first question here, so sorry if something will go wrong.

I have problem with showing my custom listview, which i tried to do similar like here: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

First, in MainActivity I'm using ViewFlipper, but i think it doesn't matter.

```
    vieFli = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    vieFli.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    View vie2 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_friends, null);
    vieFli.addView(vie2);
```

Here is the activity_friends.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FriendsActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_friend_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add friend" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/add_friend_button"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is FriendList.java (just adapter):

```
public class FriendList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] friendName;
private final Integer[] imageId;

public FriendList(Activity context, String[] friendName, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.one_row, friendName);
    this.context = context;
    this.friendName = friendName;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    txtTitle.setText(friendName[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    //txtTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return friendName.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int arg0) {
    return friendName[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}
}
```

Next I want to show you is one_row.xml (how i want to represent one row in my ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And FriendsActivity which is loaded in ViewFlipper:

```
public class FriendsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView list;
String[] friendName = {
        "Michael",
        "James"
};
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

    FriendList adapter = new FriendList(this, friendName, imageId);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            //  Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
...
```

That's simply copy of tutorial that i linked at start of post and it doesn't works for me. Could you tell me where is the problem ? As i read some other issues with that, I saw problems with xml's layouts, but can't find it in mine.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line in `getView(...)`

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row, null, true);
```

to be:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_row, parent, false);
```

Comment: still doesn't help ... still i see only button (which is above list)

Comment: Problem is from your `ViewFliper`, you should check how to use it